# AS3 Sort a Collection of Objects?

Tags: actionscript-3

In AS3, how do i sort this list alphabetically? I'm not a programming expert and i've had a hard time just figuring this out.

```
var searchObject:Object = new Object();
var mapXML:XML;
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("interactive-map.xml"));
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, parseXML);

function parseXML(event:Event):void {
    mapXML = new XML(event.target.data);
    for each (var locationElement:XML in mapXML.maplocation) {
        searchObject.locationname = locationElement.attribute("locationname");
        searchObject.category = locationElement.attribute("category");
        trace("Location Name: " + searchObject.locationname);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to push elements to array/vector.
Then you can sort array with sortOn or sort methods.
Check sortOn/sort methods reference to find sorting options.

```
var searchObject:Object = new Object();
var searchObjectArray:Array = new Array
var mapXML:XML;
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("interactive-map.xml"));
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, parseXML);

function parseXML(event:Event):void {
    mapXML = new XML(event.target.data);
    for each (var locationElement:XML in mapXML.maplocation) {
        searchObject = new Object();
        searchObject.locationname = locationElement.attribute("locationname");
        searchObject.category = locationElement.attribute("category");
        searchObjectArray.push(searchObject);//pushing elements to array
    }
    searchObjectArray.sortOn("locationname")//sorting array
    for each ( var searchObjectElement:Object in searchObjectArray)
    {
        trace("Location name: " + searchObjectElement.locationname);//printing sorted array
    }
}
```

Comment: So close! And thank you for your time -- Only problem is that it repeats out the last locationelement in the XML file over and over again, rather than tracing out all the unique location names? Any clue? Also since now everything is going into an array, do we still need the object stuff on line 1?

Comment: Reg line 1 if you want you can just push names/categories String to array and then sort. And there was bug in my code. I added searchObject = new Object(); in first loop now it should be working fine.

Comment: That's great, it works perfectly. Thanks for your time again! Have a great Sunday. So thankful!

Answer (score 0):

Try something ike this:

```
var nodes:Array = [];

for each (var locationElement:XML in mapXML.maplocation) {
   nodes[nodes.length] = locationElement;
}

nodes.sortOn(locationname);
```

I'm not sure if this will work with XML array elements. If it doesn't, try [using sort() with a compareFunction](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ee5.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fa4).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to somehow wrap this in a collection class or map it over like Amy suggests, here's an example that uses an XMLCollection http://www.webdevotion.be/blog/2008/01/22/how-to-sort-an-xmllist-using-e4x/